# Vue/ Nuxt - mounted: () => Vs mounted: function()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Why the results are different for using `() =>` and `function()` in `mounted`:

```
export default {
  mounted: () => {
    this.socket = 'something'
    console.log('mounted')
  },
  methods: {
    submitMessage() {
      console.log(this.socket) // undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Using `function()`:

```
export default {
  mounted: function() {
    this.socket = 'something'
    console.log('mounted')
  },
  methods: {
    submitMessage() {
      console.log(this.socket) // something
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This explains why: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not use an arrow function to define a lifecycle hook, methods ,... (e.g. `mounted: () => this.socket++`). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and `this.socket` will be undefined.

Comment: This is good answer. But @laukok you should learn and understand about arrow function and keyword `this` binding concept in JavaScript. It will help you a lot later. `console.log(this)` help me to know what is `this`

Comment: Thats interesting.